# User session id changed to the last user logged in using ajax login in codeigniter 3

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I have some strange behavior of login. When A login and success redirect to homepage with session of user A (And all of its data).

[User A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sO5Uc.jpg)

User B login and success redirect to homepage with session of user B

[User B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjnuC.jpg)

But session of user A immediately change to session of user B. Because i using ajax, the name of the profile change when i refresh the page. Without refresh the page, we won't notice if we already logged in as someone else.

It's my login code

```
public function login_user()
{
    $condition = [
        "email" => $this->input->post('email'),
        "password" => md5($this->input->post('password'))
    ];

    $user = $this->builtbyprime->get('baper_users', $condition, 1);

    if(count($user) > 0) {
        $data = [   
            'LOGGED_IN'    => true,
            'ID'           => $user['id'],
            'USERNAME'     => $user['nama_lengkap'],
            'STATUS'       => $user['status'],
            'ACCESS_LEVEL' => 'pengguna'
        ];

        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        redirect(base_url() . 'pengguna/homepage');

    } else {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('login', 'gagal');
        redirect(base_url());
    }
}
```

my config.php

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'baperplus';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = TRUE;


$config['cookie_prefix']    = '';
$config['cookie_domain']    = '';
$config['cookie_path']      = '/';
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
$config['cookie_httponly']  = FALSE;
```

In every controller except for authentication user i use this

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    if($this->session->ACCESS_LEVEL != 'pengguna')
    {
        redirect(base_url());
    }
}
```

Notes : IDK somehow after a while (300s i think), User A logged in in Browser A changed to User B in browser B, and after a while User A in browser A (who has changed to user B) changed again to user A and after this changed user B in browser B changed to user A.

1. User A logged in, User B logged in = User A changed to user B.
2. After a while, User A (change to B session now) refresh the browser
   and change to User A (the correct session data) but if B refresh the
   browser (to see if the session data interchanged) User B changed to
   user A and so forth again and again alternately.

Comment: you can refresh page by JavaScript after recieving `success` in Ajax

Comment: use two different browsers not two tabs

Comment: how user B is able to login  if user A is already login??

Comment: Add this lline in login `if (!isset($this->session) {...}`check whether user is already login

Comment: @AbdullaNilam I check using several browser and my several client login at the same time have same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Sessions are a relationship between a browser and a website. There can be only one session per browser/website.

You need a test to determine if that relationship already exists before you allow a login.

```
public function login_user()
{
    if($this->session->LOGGED_IN)
    {
        //somebody is already logged in on this browser
        redirect(base_url('pengguna/homepage'));
    }

    //the remainder of the code as you already have it
}
```

Not related to your problem but something to consider is the use of all uppercase key names in the `$data` array.

By convention in PHP all UPPERCASE is used to indicate a constant. You should consider the confusion you might be creating for other developers reading this code in the future. Consider doing this instead:

```
$data = [
    'logged_in' => true,
    'id' => $user['id'],
    'username' => $user['nama_lengkap'],
    'status' => $user['status'],
    'access_level' => 'pengguna'
];
```